# Animating width of div and limiting to max-width using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, window-resize

My container div contain two divs div box1 and div box2. box2 is absolute div with max width of 400px;

html:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2 animated"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#container{position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;background:red;} 

#container #box1{position:relative;width:760px;height:300px;background:blue;margin:0;} 

#container #box2{position:absolute;width:60px;max-width:350px;height:300px;background:yellow;;top:0;}
```

jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var box1width = $(".box1").width();
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var x = windowWidth - (box1width + 350 ) ;
    var wdt = windowWidth - (box1width) ;


    if (".box2").hasClass("animated"){
       if(x > windowWidth ){
       $(".box2").animate({width:'350px'}, 2000); 
       } else { 
       $(".box2").animate({width: wdt+ 'px'}, 2000);
       } 
    } else {

    alert("no animation for box2 nd width remain 60px");
    }

    });
```

Initially this animate my box2width;Now I want to animate box2 width on window resize as well as limit my box2 animate width upto 350px only;

Comment: You sounds like this code is partially working. but it's throwing error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . ` a working fiddle would make it easy to solve the problem

Comment: and you  haven't shared the `animated` class..

Comment: This is working for me;I dont know whether there is any mistake while writing this question. Actually I can do with window.resize function, but i dont waat to fire  method hasClass("animated") on each occasion of window.resize.

Comment: The code you shared has lots of syntx errors. it's throwing error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .` Try copy pasting the exact working code.. or a working fiddle would make it easy to solve the problem

Comment: This animated class has nothing to animate with css , this is actually a variable class to indication for animation , in other case this cass should be no-animation;

Comment: You want to animate `box2` on page load and resize if it has `350px` width and if it's less than `350px` you simply want to show it without animating, am i right?

Comment: yess tilwin!I want to animated box2 between 60px and 350px, only if there is space to animate. on initial load as well as on window resize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/Dzw9t/)

```
if (!$(".box2").hasClass("animated")) {
     if (wdt >= 60) {
         $(".box2").animate({
             width: '350px'
         }, 2000);
         $(".box2").addClass('animated');
     }
 } else {
         if (wdt <= 350) {
             $(".box2").css('width','60px');
             $(".box2").removeClass('animated');
         }
     }
```

*side note: not sure if this is exactly what you want, if not comment below :)*

**update as per comments** [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/Dzw9t/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 anime();
 var resizeTimer;
 window.onresize = function () {
     if (resizeTimer) {
         clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
     }
     resizeTimer = setTimeout(function () {
         anime();
     }, 200);
 }
})
 function anime() {
 var windowWidth = $(window).width();
 var box1width = $(".box1").width();
 var wdt = windowWidth - (box1width);
 if (wdt > 60) {
     $(".box2").stop(true,true).animate({
         width: wdt
     }, 1000);
     $(".box2").addClass('animated');
 } else if($(".box2").hasClass('animated')){
   $(".box2").css('width', '60px');
   $(".box2").removeClass('animated');
 }
}
```

*Note: this is just a fix for what you're trying to do, i'd prefer css3 transition over this..*

Comment: This animating only if there is space more than 350px; I want to animate box2 between 60px to 350px on window resize. this box can take  width as 100px or 200px or 350px.

Comment: Your question is not clear.. this is not what you mentioned in the question.. you've said anything about `100px`, `200px` etc in your question.. please update the question properly.. BTW this is what i came up with http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/Dzw9t/
only if you explain the problem properly others can help you solve it..

Comment: I am just telling that my width may be anywhere between 60px and 350px; so it may be 100px or 200 or anything between 60px to 350px;

Comment: okay, so resize event will be thrown hundreds of times while resizing, if you keep animating while there's more than 60px width available the animation will start over and over causing flicker.. How do you want to handle that? do you just want to animate only once after resizing?

Comment: Thanks for the help! Partially I achieved it, box2 width is animating, just need to set it on window resize.

Comment: yeah Thats what I want to explain! Instead of firing animation and checking hasClass on each resize event and  , I want to set a timeout so after resize box2 animate to with with proper animation!

Comment: Yess! Solved it, Thanks Tilwin